# Android Studio-made classes have errors - what is happening here?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I assume this is some kind of build issue, but I don't understand why at the moment. All I am doing is importing adroid.database.sqllite classes yet they appear to have errors inside them.

I am new to Android development so perhaps the answer is basic, but what is going on here?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Try clicking File>Invalidate caches see if that fixes it

Answer (score 0):

*you must complete the code*

- Instead of `SQL_CREATE_ENTERIES` write your create-tables queries like
  `DB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE User_table ( id numeric,name text)");` 
  `DB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Movie_table ( id numeric,name text)");`
  and instead of `SQL_DELETE_ENTERIES`  write your tables Migration, but for start just drop the old table like
   `DB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_table" );`
   `DB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS movie_table" );`
- for the `import...` statements errors, just delete the red once then go to the class to regenerate all of them, by putting the cursor on the red Objects (like `@UnsupportedAppUsage`) and press **(ctrl+space)** then press **(enter)**, then you note the error gone.
  there are many reasons why that happened, maybe the direction of libraries change because you use androidx or something else، it does not matter
- `1 related problem` error I don't know what the error is, but just press **(ctrl)** then **click in the constructor** `FeedReaderDBHelper(Context context)`, to go where is the reason of the error